# text disappear when goes outside marked area Open Layer

Tags: openlayers

Inside marked Area I write some text. When  I zoom out, text goes out outside Area and disappear. Is there any way to prevent this?

I was trying to change text size depending on Zoom size so that it always match inside the area and never disappear but it only catch the zoom once and later do not change anything.

Below part of my code.

```
var styleText = function(text) {
    var zoom = map.getView().getZoom();
    var resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    var font = zoom * 3
    return {
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: font+'px Courier New',
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffd300'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#000',
                width: 3
            }),
            textAlign: "center",
            textBaseline: "middle",
            text:  text,
        })
    }
}

    var newVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        name: areaIncra.farmId,
        source: kmlVector,
        style:   new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: 'red',
              width: 3
          }),
          text: styleText('Text to show').text
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the style to be recalculated it needs to be a function

```
    style: function(feature, resolution) { return new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'red',
          width: 3
      }),
      text: styleText('Text to show').text
  }); }
```

You might also want to set `overflow: true` on `ol.style.Text` https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.style.Text.html

```js
var styleText = function(text) {
var zoom = map.getView().getZoom();
var resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
var font = (zoom + 1) * 3;
return {
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: font+'px Courier New',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#ffd300'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#000',
            width: 3
        }),
        textAlign: "center",
        textBaseline: "middle",
        text: text,
        overflow: true
    })
}
}

var newVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector(),
style: function(feature, resolution) {
    return new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'red',
            width: 3
        }),
        text: styleText('Text to show').text
    });
}
});

var map = new ol.Map({
layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    }),
    newVector
],
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
})
});

map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: newVector.getSource(),
  type: 'Polygon',
}));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: I've adding a working snippet where you can draw polygons.  I had no problems but using your code at zoom level 0 the font size was 0 which is invalid and might cause problems with some browsers so I changed it to `(zoom+1)*3`